# Why is my Vizio TV seemingly probing my LAN?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, smart-tv

I assigned our Vizio TV a static address on our WLAN to allow me to track its traffic.

The Linux machines on the LAN are constantly blocking UDP probes that the Vizio is sending.  They look like this in the UFW syslog entries:

```
19 01:30:09 Ubuntu6 kern.4 kernel:  [33210.081447] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=192.168.1.XXX DST=192.168.1.YYY LEN=542 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38134 DPT=38921 LEN=522 
19 01:30:09 Ubuntu6 kern.4 kernel:  [33211.002642] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=192.168.1.XXX DST=192.168.1.YYY LEN=542 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=45557 DPT=38921 LEN=522 
19 01:30:10 Ubuntu6 kern.4 kernel:  [33212.025883] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=192.168.1.XXX DST=192.168.1.YYY LEN=542 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35343 DPT=38921 LEN=522 
19 01:30:12 Ubuntu6 kern.4 kernel:  [33213.047369] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=192.168.1.XXX DST=192.168.1.YYY LEN=542 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=47666 DPT=38921 LEN=522
```

The destination ports change every few minutes, and the probes seem to occur in sets of four.

I'm wondering if it's multicast or mDNS-related or hopefully something innocuous, though I don't like this behavior.  I moved the Vizio to a separate VLAN, however this isn't ideal because we can't easily cast to it.

I can't find any Vizio settings to turn the behavior off, and Google searches haven't turned up anything.  Appreciate any hints or help!

Comment: It's probably probing your LAN.  Whether this is bad behavior by design of the manufacturer, or bad behavior by design of someone who's broken in since then, hard to say.  I don't buy Smart TVs for this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Vizio TV supports Google Cast which uses multicast for discovery.  This traffic is normal.

It's basically saying to every device on your network, "Hey, I'm here, want to talk to me?"  Some [details from Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/technotes/7-6/chromecastDG76/ChromecastDG76.html):

> Chromecast uses a simple multicast protocol for Discovery And Launch that enables users to mirror their devices on a second screen.
>
> The Chromecast devices operate on DIAL protocol. The DIAL Service Discovery enables a client to discover DIAL Server (Chromecast) on its local network, and obtain access to those services. This is achieved by using a new search target within the SSDP defined by uPNP.
>
> The clients that wishes to discover Chromecast servers send a request over UDP...

Comment: +1 A link to the source would be cool.

Comment: @JimL.Done.  It's two years old, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you Jason.  (I don't have enough points to upvote you.)